# Do not refresh Inner Update Panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using 2 `Update Panel` in Asp.net. Second `Update Panel` is inside main `Update Panel`. It is like as below :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
            // Google Map...
         </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`UpdatePanel1` contains `Dropdown` and It is `Autupostback=true` so if user selects any `Dropdown` then it refreshs `Google Map` which is inside. I do not want to refresh inside `Update Panel` anyway.
Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: The way update panels work is that the entire content is replaced when they update. If you want something more fine grained then don't use an update panel.

Comment: @BenRobinson, I don't want to refresh page when user selects any dropdown. So, what is the another way to do this ?

Comment: You could use JQuery and create a web service. You can do pretty much anything you want with that.

Answer (score 0):

People often misunderstand the way UpdatePanel works. They mistakenly think that, there's no page reload   when anything triggering postback occurs inside an UpdatePanel. This is totally wrong. In fact a full page reload is taken place. It's not a coincidence that UpdatePanel is located under category called AJAX controls of the toolbox. But it does not work the same as AJAX does, it just imitates it. What you get when you use UpdatePanel is that the page does not flicker to the top of the page, which is the normal behavior of any full page reload, so you get a feeling of partial refresh. That's why, the Google Maps you're talking about gets refreshed. Using real AJAX will help you do just what you want. Jquery library has a very convenient way of doing AJAX. Or you can just use plain javascript.